# android studio/intellij IDEA with libgdx error 'compilation completed with 16 errors' 'Error:(3, 24) java: package com.badlogic.gdx does not exist'

Tags: android, intellij-idea, libgdx

after creating project with libgdx, by opening/importing with both android studio/intellij IDEA i get same errors on both of them tried google and other stack,s answers didn't helped.

[image: error with android studio]

[image: error with intellij IDEA]

my gradle build

```
buildscript {

  repositories {
      mavenLocal()
      mavenCentral()
      maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
      jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {

  }
}

allprojects {
apply plugin: "eclipse"
apply plugin: "idea"

version = '1.0'
ext {
    appName = "my-gdx-game"
    gdxVersion = '1.9.6'
    roboVMVersion = '2.3.1'
    box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
    ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
    aiVersion = '1.8.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"       }
  }
 }

  project(":desktop") {
     apply plugin: "java"


   dependencies {
       compile project(":core")
       compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
       compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"

      }
    }

  project(":core") {
   apply plugin: "java"


   dependencies {
      compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
      compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
      compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
      compile "com.badlogicgames.ashley:ashley:$ashleyVersion"
      compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"

   }
  }

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Comment: refresh dependency ?

Comment: yes refreshed gradle/reimported/restarted project but no changes

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the `gdx.jar` is missing in your classpath.

Use `Import project` instead of `Open an existing AS project`.

Then click `Refresh all Gradle project` (two circular arrow) that is available on top of Gradle Project menu.

For Gradle Project Menu use :

MenuBar's menu `View` -> `Tools Windows` -> `Gradle`

---

Create a fresh new project :

1. run `gdx-setup.jar` by click or you can use `cmd`
2. Fill all Textfield with required value.
3. Select Sub Projects that you want in your project.
4. If you need extension select.
5. Click `Advanced` button and select `IDEA` and click Save.
6. Generate.

After successful creation of your project, import<sup>*</sup> your project in Android Studio/IntellijIDEA. Select root level `build.gradle` file of project at the time of import.

*<sub>Required good internet connection while you importing your project 1<sup>st</sup> time.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me

1. Turning off fire wall in antivirus(avast)
2. Opening `cmd` going to root folder, and used this command
   `gradlew clean build`

Screen shot [here is the cmd command for gradle to download dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVFWT.png)